# Gluing construction of the projective space scheme.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space

When constructing the projective space scheme $\mathbb{P}_R^n$ for a ring $R$, we may take the subrings
$$
A_i = R\left[\tfrac{X_0}{X_i}, \ldots, \widehat{\tfrac{X_i}{X_i}}, \ldots, \tfrac{X_n}{X_i}\right],
\; i = 0, \ldots, n,
$$
of the ring $A^{(0)}$of homogenous elements of $A = R[X_0, \ldots, X_n, X_0^{-1},\ldots, X_n^{-1}]$ and glue the affine schemes $U_i = \text{Spec}(A_i)$ together along the open subschemes $U_{ij} \subseteq U_i$ with
$$
U_{ij} = D_{U_i}\bigl(\tfrac{X_j}{X_i}\bigr) \cong \text{Spec}\left(A_i\left[\left(\tfrac{X_j}{X_i}\right)^{-1}\right]\right)
$$

I read that we can use the identity to glue, but why (and how) is
$$
A_i\left[\left(\tfrac{X_j}{X_i}\right)^{-1}\right]
\cong
A_j\left[\left(\tfrac{X_i}{X_j}\right)^{-1}\right]
$$
for $i \neq j$?

Comment: Actually we have equality: $
A_i\left[\left(\tfrac{X_j}{X_i}\right)^{-1}\right]
=
A_j\left[\left(\tfrac{X_i}{X_j}\right)^{-1}\right]
$ Try to write everything explicitly for $n=3, i=1, j=2$

Comment: I'm probably missing intuition about localizations here, sorry! So you are saying we have $R\bigl[\tfrac{X_0}{X_1},\tfrac{X_2}{X_1},\tfrac{X_3}{X_1}\bigr][(X_2/X_1)^{-1}]
=
R\bigl[\tfrac{X_0}{X_2},\tfrac{X_1}{X_2},\tfrac{X_3}{X_2}\bigr][(X_1/X_2)^{-1}]$ here?

Comment: Yes, exactly: take any element on one of the sides of the equality and realize that it is also in the other side! Also, forget about localizations: $A_i\left[\left(\tfrac{X_j}{X_i}\right)^{-1}\right]=A_i[\tfrac{X_i}{X_j}] $ etc.